# Turning C# delegates into unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing

In order to reduce code duplication I would like to generate unit tests programatically from various sources. One simple way I could think of was to generate a whole bunch of delegates from within a method that parses some configuration information and tags all those delegates with the `[TestMethod]` attribute which are then run by the visual studio test framework.

My motivation is to use as much of the visual studio's test reporting facilities as possible because I could write my own reporting layer for the tests by using some of C#'s reflection facilities but I rather not. My solution seems pretty elegant and simple but I can't get visual studio's test framework to understand what exactly I'm trying to do so does anyone know how to go about doing what I would like?

Comment: I think it is best practice to keep all data relevant to the unit test in the file the test is defined in - aren't you concerned that this may obscure the purpose of the tests?

Comment: The configuration information will be right next to the tests so it won't be hard to follow what the tests are doing.

Comment: Then maybe it can be achieved using the [TestCase](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.5.9) attribute?

Comment: `TestCase` won't help because the test data is generated dynamically based on various requirements which I don't control and is not known until compile time.

Comment: So if I understood it correctly, you would like to generate Test-classes dynamically and on top of that, it is a requirement that no fixed data is used as input for every method to test?

Comment: @Sander Pham: Fixed data can be used but on top of the fixed data there will be some dynamically generated information for stress testing and various other scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) (and possibly [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) for legacy code) from Microsoft Research.  Pex is a research project that automatically generates unit tests with high code coverage, and supposedly picks interesting input and outputs for the tests.  I guess there's some intelligence there.  :)

I have not personally used it, but I have heard from some peers that Pex and Moles is pretty interesting and has helped them out.  May be worth a look.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think if you actually want to generate tests, you'd be best off literally generating the tests, using something like [T4 templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx?ppud=4).  In other words, use code-generation and create the test fixtures and methods such that you run them as you would any other test case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if this does not answer you question exactly but I think that auto-generating unit tests is the wrong way to tackle this problem.
Unit tests are an effective way to help avoid regression and provide documentation to how your code should be used.  When you automatically generate your tests you get a bunch of tests but if they fail you don't really know if a real bug exist and you end up with a lot of failing tests that you have no idea why they fail or how to make them pass. At the end you would probably delete all of the tests - because they "don't work".

Having said that - try out [Armadillo](http://www.armadilloverdrive.com/) from Typemock - it's a tool that writes the tests according to the user's actions

Comment: Everyone keeps bringing up this point but it doesn't make any sense. The whole point of testing is to weed out bugs and provide documentation and generating tests from config files that clearly show what the inputs and outputs should be is just as good. Nobody blinks an eye when ORM mappers are used to automatically generated scaffolding for database access but everyone keeps crying about generating test cases from various config files.

Comment: That's not exactly the same - do you use ORM as a documentation. tests without logic behind them are valid "smoke tests" that might or might not be good for your project but do not replace old fashioned hand written unit tests that actually test logic and not just set -> set -> get